# How do I add all resource arn's? Lambda Golang ListTags

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I am trying to list out all tags of my lambda functions, struggling a lot, please help me if anyone knows.

```
func main() {

    svc := lambda.New(session.New())

    input := &lambda.ListTagsInput{

        Resource: aws.String("arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:657907747545:function-function-name"),
```

I'm expecting to list  all tag arn's for my lambda functions

Comment: What is your question? What did you expect to happen and what happened instead ?

Comment: Like I want to list Tags for all my lambda functions with go lang, instead I'm able to take only 1 arn in the resource, How do I do that, Please help me.

Comment: well, you first need to list all your lambda function and then run a for loop to list the tags of each lambda functions....

Comment: I wanna list tags for all the lambda functions not for a single resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    awsutils "github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/lambda"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

var lambdaClient *lambda.Client = nil
var once sync.Once

func init() {
    once.Do(func() {
        cfg, err := awsutils.New()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        lambdaClient = lambda.New(lambda.Options{Credentials: cfg.Credentials, Region: cfg.Region})
    })
}

func ListLambdas() ([]string, error) {
    f, err := lambdaClient.ListFunctions(context.Background(), &lambda.ListFunctionsInput{})

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var functions = make([]string, len(f.Functions))
    for i, functionName := range f.Functions {
        functions[i] = *functionName.FunctionName
    }

    continuationToken := f.NextMarker
    for continuationToken != nil {
        f, err = lambdaClient.ListFunctions(context.Background(), &lambda.ListFunctionsInput{Marker: continuationToken})
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        continuationToken = f.NextMarker
        for _, functionName := range f.Functions {
            functions = append(functions, *functionName.FunctionName)
        }
    }
    return functions, nil
}

func DescribeLambda(lambdaName string) (*lambda.GetFunctionOutput, error) {
    function, err := lambdaClient.GetFunction(context.Background(), &lambda.GetFunctionInput{FunctionName: aws.String(lambdaName)})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return function, nil
}

func ListTags(lambdaARN string) (*lambda.ListTagsOutput, error) {
    return lambdaClient.ListTags(context.Background(), &lambda.ListTagsInput{
        Resource: aws.String(lambdaARN),
    })
}
```

Then you can use the `ListLambdas` method in order to list all your lambda. After, you can iterate the slice returned and call the `DescribeLambda` method in order to get the `lambdaARN`, then you can call the `ListTags`.

You can refer to the following repository in order to understand how to work with AWS (lambda, S3, glue etc etc) in Golang: https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/tree/master/aws

Comment: running this code but getting the following error

Comment: cannot initiate duplicate method, go mod requires 1.15

Comment: Try to rename the package to main, i've update the code. Please paste here your solution: https://play.golang.com/

Comment: # github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2@v1.17.1/aws/retryer.go:81:2: duplicate method GetInitialToken
note: module requires Go 1.15

Comment: facing this again :(

Comment: I think that you are using an old version of Go, before the modules. Try to update your go version. And post a complete exemple in play.golang.com

Comment: # command-line-arguments
runtime.main_main·f: function main is undeclared in the main package

Comment: updated the go version now I'm using the 1.15.5

Comment: Update to 1.19.3 and post your code. The function shared are working (i use them in a lot of projects)

Comment: but if am running this code on go playground with go 1.19 its saying go running failed.

anyways will update it to go 1.19

Comment: updated to go 1.19, 

getting this error command-line-arguments runtime.main_main·f: function main is undeclared in the main package

Comment: Because you have not declared a `main` function. Copy and paste my code and than use it in your main